# Strange printing error when including different PDFs

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, graphics, pdf, printing

First of all: I was not able to compile a MWE, since the error seems to be connected to one of my documents, all of which are classified.

I'm experiencing (for the first time) the following error:

When opening a file in Acrobat Reader and then trying to print, I receive the errors

```
The document could not be printed
There were no pages selected to print
```

My file is structured as follows:

```
A beamer-file created in LuaLatex

In the beamer-file, several other PDFs are included. Either created by AutoCAD or - and this seems to be the problem - by Latex (pdflatex).

Some of the other PDF-files are included inside a tikz-environment (if that matters).

All PDF pages are included as images using the graphics-package.
```

By trying to include different PDFs and varying the amount of PDFs I discovered that the problem seems to be that different pages are included in different tikz-environments (it could be a completely different reason as well, this is just a feeling).

I've created several other presentations using beamer all of which included multiple PDFs - but those PDFs were NOT Latex-created files. These other presentations work (and print) like a charm.

Using a different PDF viewer solves the problem. However, as the created presentation will be sent off to customers, using a different PDF viewer is no valid solution.

Also, the problem seems to be connected to some printers. E.g. using CutePDF causes the error, while (sometimes) using the network HP printer works.

Answer (score 1):

Your description is somewhat vague, but I faced a similar problem in the past and solved it by rasterising the included pdfs using ImageMagick.

You can try it as follows:

```
convert -density 300 <input.pdf> <output.pdf>
```

where the density parameter controls the rendering quality.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm using a Windows-machine at work, so all the clever Linux-tricks will not work for me...

Comment: You can use ImageMagick under Windows:https://imagemagick.org/script/binary-releases.php#windows